# How to get sum of invoices across join table in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have these models in my Rails 4 app:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many  :allocations
  has_many  :payments, :through => :allocations

end
```

---

```
class Allocation < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :payment

end
```

---

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many    :allocations
  has_many    :invoices, :through => :allocations

end
```

Obviously, it is possible that one `payment` belongs to many `invoices`.

In the `Payment` model I have this function that sums the total of all the `invoices` that one specific payment relates to:

```
def invoice_total_of_siblings
  invoice_ids = Allocation.where(:payment_id => id).map(&:invoice_id)
  invoices = Invoice.where(:id => invoice_ids)
  invoices.to_a.sum(&:total)
end
```

However, this function feels cumbersome and I wonder how it could be made more concise.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try `Invoice.where(:id => invoice_ids).sum(:total)`.. It should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your set of associations (payment has many invoices through allocations), you could simply do this:

```
def invoice_total_of_siblings
    invoices.sum(:total)
end
```

EDIT:
This solution works as-is for database fields, provided that the given set is an ActiveRecord association.

In this speicific case, however, as it is produced from the comments, `total` is a calculated field. Hence, the given set will not be an ActiveRecord association, but an Array. Then, you will need to map the field in order to sum it. The correct syntax in this case will be:

```
def invoice_total_of_siblings
    invoices.sum(&:total)
end
```

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. Much simpler than I thought. I have to use `&:total` to make it work, though. I wonder why that is.

Comment: @Tintin81 You have to use `&:`,because `invoices` will give you `Array` of `Invoice` objects.

Comment: :total is a field from the invoices table?

Comment: @RubyRacer: No, it's being calculated from a database field called `total_in_cents`. That's probably why I need the `&`.

Comment: Ok, that's why you need the `&`... It's a mapped field... If it where a db column field, then you shouldn't put `&`... I'll fix my answer to show this.

Comment: Remember: It's always helpful, as you have done, to be as verbose as possible in defining associations... It will help build your code very, very easily..